# EAS Build (Android) .apk Crashes, Expo Build .apk Runs Correctly

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm updating a React Native app to EAS Build, after using expo build for several years. The app works via the development server.

After running eas build, the .apk file builds successfully, but immediately crashes when opened on a device.

My error log is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.indexOf')
Running "main" with {"rootTag":1}
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Has anyone run into this error?

Comment: hi there! try out the troubleshooting techniques from the EAS Build docs and follow up with any more information that you can share: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/

Comment: thanks @brentvatne! i ran through the docs and I'm still hitting a brick wall in regards to how to get a more actionable error message / stacktrace. Do you have any advice around this?

Comment: there's some useful information about what you can provide to help people to help you debug at the bottom of that page: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/#still-having-trouble

Comment: How did you see the crash log?

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems, but after reading the documentation some things changed.

1. Are you migrating an Expo managed app from "expo build"? [Learn about the differences](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/).
2. They must create an index file ([reference](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#custom--main--entry-point-in)), with:

   ```
   import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
   import App from './src/App';

   registerRootComponent(App);
   ```

   (If the `App.js` is in the root, delete the `/src` so they have `./App`)

   And then, from the `package.json`, delete the entire line of `main`.
3. And [this is the most difficult step]
   (https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#metroconfigjs--must-export-the-entire-default

, it cost me

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the final step? You correctly do this the second link, in particular, but this answer ultimately relies on information that won't be useful if the page the last link points to is later (re)moved.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.